# What is the cover of Reset! Chapter 2 a reference to?

Tags: reset

I've read three chapters of the manga Reset!, which takes place in the same world as Yuru Yuri. Each chapter's cover seems to be a reference to some other work. For example, here's the Chapter 3 cover:

[image: Chapter 3 cover]

Which is a reference to this famous Kanon image:

[image: Kanon image]

Here's the cover of Chapter 1:

[image: Reset! Chapter 1 cover]

Which I believe is a reference to this Little Busters image:

[image: Little Busters image]

Here's the cover of Chapter 2:

[image: Reset! Chapter 2 cover]

I cannot figure out what this image is referring to. Since the other two were works by Key, I checked into Clannad, Air, and Rewrite, but none of them seem to match that logo. Does anyone recognize this image?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now I feel stupid...

A little thought and twenty minutes with Google image search has got me pretty sure that this cover is a reference to Kud Wafter:

[image]

Kud Wafter is the spinoff of Little Busters that continues the story of Kudryavka Noumi, in the same way that Tomoyo After continues the story of Tomoyo Sakagami from Clannad. I forgot the spinoffs existed, so I didn't look into them.

The Reset! character on the Chapter 2 cover uses the name "Kudryavka" as a *nom de plume* for her poetry, which makes it pretty near a sure thing.